# Кроссплатформенное приложение с интерфейсом в стиле FAR

Tags: java, visual-c++, c++builder

Одной моей ученице на первом (!) курсе задали написать игру "змейка". Чтобы внятно объяснить ей, как такое писать, я решил для начала написать это сам и в ходе действия столкнулся вот с какой проблемой.

Они работают с Visual Studio. Для разработки программы, которая что-то рисует в консоли, требуется функция очистки консоли (чтобы перерисовывать игровое поле, напечатанное символами псевдографики), функция позиционирования в консоли (чтобы перерисовывать не всё игровое поле, а только её необходимую область) и функция обработки клавиш со стрелками для перемещения змейки.

Все эти функции есть в Borland C++ Builder (ещё и с раскрашиванием консоли до кучи), но в Visual Studio есть только последняя (`getch`), и то это нестандарт. Для очистки консоли надо написать `system("cls")` (я так понимаю, cls - это команда оболочки Windows, которая не факт что будет работать в других ОС'ах), а чтобы реализовать аналог `gotoxy`, вообще необходимо подключить `Windows.h` и вызывать функции WinAPI. Но когда я это делаю, у меня перестаёт компилироваться программа при включенной опции компилятора Disable language extensions. Сами Microsoft пишут, что эта опция нужна для обеспечения кроссплатформенности. И вот тут я задумался, а возможно ли вообще написать кроссплатформенную программу с подобным интерфейсом, раз получается, что её невозможно сделать, не используя ни борландовские, ни майкрософтовские расширения C++? Ведь в справочнике по C++ ясно сказано, что стандартная библиотека в принципе не позволяет обрабатывать ввод одиночного символа без Enter.

Я попробовал погуглить, как с этим в насквозь кроссплатформенной Java, и у меня создалось впечатление, что на Java такую программу вообще написать невозможно. Кстати, даже если не пытаться делать что-то такое олдскульное, как графика в консоли, в окошках с кроссплатформенностью тоже не так хорошо: например, вот: [Иконка в трее в Java](http://eax.me/java-tray-icon/). Кроме того, я сталкивался с тем, что одна программа, написанная на QT (тоже типа кроссплатформенном) работала, только если в мастере совместимости программ отключить для неё визуальные стили Windows, в противном случае вместо окна на экране отображалась узкая полоска.

Единственное решение, которое мне приходит в голову - это взять заголовочный файл conio.h в борландовском варианте, где всё нужное есть, и реализовать его самостоятельно в отдельном файле `*.c`, и реализация этого файла будет разной для разных платформ. Собственно, примерно так я и сделал. Возможно, другие пользователи знают решение лучше.

Comment: Консоль это же принтер, у него в общем случае нет перемотки бумаги назад. Все что есть в каждой конкретной ОС по определению непереносимо. Если нужно переносимое управление экраном, то надо брать не консоль, а оконное приложение. Или та же Ява, или если для  С++ то какое-нибудь Qt.

Comment: можно пробовать использовать `putchar('\f')`, а так же `'\r'` и `'\b'`, но ничего не гарантирую. Думаю, твой вариант с отдельной реализацией conio.h для каждой системы - лучший.

Comment: Кстати, `getch` в VS2005 точно глючил. Точнее, он как бы работал, но когда оказывался в сочетании с scanf, то возникали какие-то косяки.